# how to sort in bash based on file name

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sorting

how to use find command for right sorting  in bash shell .
for example ,

```
file name                   size              
---------------------------------------------
aa.txt                          346
bb.txt                          29
cc.txt                          36
dd.txt                          856
```

and so on .. 
if i try this for making array to deal with size like below

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" | sort -nk9
```

then listed value not mached for list of file name  ... how to sorting according to filename ?

```
declare -a size=$(find . -type f -iname "*.txt" | sort -nk9 )   
            size_array=$(size)
```

always should be out put like this (346,29,36,856) based on actually order of filename so can be two array last one is (aa.txt, bb.txt, cc.txt,dd.txt )
first file have to match  first size element .. but in this case not matched .. how to this ??

final out put i want !  with  bash find command

```
filename=(aa.txt, bb.txt, cc.txt,dd.txt)
filesize=(346,29,36,856)
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Can you be more clear?

Comment: always should be out put  like this   (346,29,36,856)  based on  actually order of filename so can be two array  last one is (aa.txt, bb.txt, cc.txt,dd.txt ) .

Comment: An array containing the sizes of the files should be the output?

Comment: I don't understand the English in this question. What does "*,then problems i can faced*" mean? Or "*actually listed number itself if then . can not deal as array*"? There's no sample input/output either.

Comment: What does "*listed value not mached for list of file name*" mean?

Comment: to print file size and name, sorted by name try: `find  . -type f -ls | sort -k11 | awk '{ print $7 "\t" $11 }'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is still not very clear. But from my understanding of what is required, a rough solution would be

```
files=$(find . -type f -iname "*.txt" | sort)
file_sizes=$(find . -type f -iname "*.txt" | sort | xargs -I{} stat -f%z {})
```

file names are in the files variable, and file sizes are in the file_sizes variable, sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: YOU ARE MY KING AND TEACHER!!  yes i have test this solution , very nice work !!

Comment: Note that this (like the original code) doesn't actually create bash arrays, just string variables with spaces embedded between names/sizes).

Comment: I couldn't actually figure out the exact requirement, so I started out with a rough suggestion.

Comment: In addition to what @GordonDavisson said... This will also fail if a pathname contains a newline character `\n`. Do this instead: `file_sizes=$(find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 -I{} stat -f%z {})`. i.e. **1)** Add the `-print0` option to `find` cmd to print the current file to `stdout` followed by a NUL character instead of a newline. **2)** Use `sort` with the `-z` option to end each line with a NUL character, instead of newline. **3** Use `xargs` with the `-0` option so it reads NUL characters as separators, instead of spaces and newlines.